# failure in rosmaking files

Tags: rosmake

[image: Rosanswers logo]

when I rosmake any file ,it has error and warning,like: rosmake arbotix, the results are as follows,

```
[ rosmake ] rosmake starting...                                                 
[ rosmake ] Packages requested are: ['arbotix']                                 
[ rosmake ] Logging to directory /home/yanglan/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20140403-111529
[ rosmake ] Expanded args ['arbotix'] to:
[]                                    
[ rosmake ] WARNING: The following args could not be parsed as stacks or packages: ['arbotix']
[ rosmake ] ERROR: No arguments could be parsed into valid package or stack names.
```

then I can not launch the note.
what can I do to solve it ,thank you!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/147876/failure-in-rosmaking-files/) by [danmianjing_00](https://answers.ros.org/users/14196/danmianjing_00/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2014-04-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

rosmake does not find your package arbotix, which indicates that you have not set up your environment properly.

Which version of ROS are you using and where is the arbotix package located? How did your get the code? (Edit your question to include all this information).

**Edit:** I'm pretty sure you have not set up your environemnt successfully if rosmake does not find the package `arbotix`.

You will want to have something like the following lines in your `.bashrc`:

```
source /opt/ros/groovy/setup.bash
export ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=~/arbotix:$ROS_PACKAGE_PATH
```

---

Originally posted by [demmeln](https://answers.ros.org/users/1370/demmeln/) with karma: 4306 on 2014-04-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [danmianjing_00](https://answers.ros.org/users/14196/danmianjing_00/) on 2014-04-03**:
I'm using groovy on ubuntu 12.04,I get the code through svn checkout http://vanadium-ros-pkg.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/arbotix,   and it is located in the home folder. I have set up my environment successfully.

**Comment by [danmianjing_00](https://answers.ros.org/users/14196/danmianjing_00/) on 2014-04-14**:
Hello,demmeln ,when I want to rosmake files ,I must run the two cmmands you refered above before rosmaking files , if not ,I would get errors like that ,this would be a little troublesome I think,how could I do to solve it permanently? Thank you!

**Comment by [demmeln](https://answers.ros.org/users/1370/demmeln/) on 2014-04-15**:
You can add them to your .bashrc file so that they get executed automatically every time you open a terminal.